# Angular 5 cannot load data jsonp from url

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I feel like I’m missing something really simple.

I made a blank ionic project and I need to pull data from a URL spitting out JSONP.

Here’s what my home.ts looks like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { RedditData } from '../../providers/reddit-data/reddit-data'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { UsingObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/UsingObservable';
import { Jsonp } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

 result:any = [];
 data:Observable<any>;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private http: HttpClient,private json:Jsonp) {

    }

ionViewDidLoad(){

    var url='/common/v1/airport.json?code=BGW&';
    this.data=this.json.request(url,'callback=JSONP_CALLBACK');
    this.data.subscribe(data =>{
        this.result=data;
        console.log(data)
    });
  }


}
```

When I am running on local server I get message in console Google Chrome:

> failed  GET /common/v1/airport.json?code=BGW&  418 ()

[image: you can see picture]

Comment: Remove that useless images and paste actual error messages from console.

Comment: same problem i dont know where is the problem

Comment: @AliGhassan can you show me your json structure

Comment: @Nikson you can check here https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=303910db558a418985fddc308f7b2942

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
this.http.get(`http://url`).subscribe(
            data => {
                 this.result=data;
                 console.log(data)
            });
```

Comment: thanks for answer , same problem , No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , we need jsonp to fix , if i change `this.http.request ` working fine but he get the url in toLowerCase , `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`